# Is there a way to serve a dynamic (config data changing) apk file in my web service?

Tags: android, web-applications

What I mean is, I want to know which device downloaded this specific apk file.

Let's just say I want to have a single string key that is provided by my webapp that my android application can resolve.

To make it more realistic, I want to know how many people will download the apk that a specific user of my webapp shared and the counter will just be incremented when the apk is successfully installed and the app is opened.

The link that is shared by the user is just opened via the device browser.

So, I think I need my android app to know the `userId` of the user that shared it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the APK gonna be download through another android app? Aside from the `userId` of that certain app user, you might want to check out the device's IMEI, which is a unique value. I'm honestly quite confused with your question for a bit.

Comment: The apk can be downloaded via browser be it from desktop or from device. Since em only serving webpages, can't access IMEI of the device.

Comment: How are the APK shared though? Is it via a link that is sent through email or an in-app message? I think the easiest way to approach it is to attach the `userId` in the link as a variable.